# Purpose of __USE_XOPEN2K8 and how to set it?

Tags: gcc, glibc

I'm trying to compile the gtk stack (the last gtk2 version, 2.24), and I am getting a bunch of errors that seem related. Namely, the `__locale_t` can't be found from string.h and time.h, and `LC_ALL_MASK` can't be found either (should be in locale.h).

I found that all of these problems are related to `__USE_XOPEN2K8` not being #defined. What is `__USE_XOPEN2K8` for, and how can I set it propertly?

For example, do I have to pass a flag to ./configure for glib, gtk, ... or do I have to change something already while building gcc or glib**c̲**? I'd rather not just sprinkle `#define __USE_XOPEN2K8` in to my sources without knowing what it does. Note I'm using gcc-4.6.3 and glibc-2.16.0 which are installed in a nonstandard prefix, as I'm trying to get the gtk libraries to work on an older CentOS (5.8) that only includes older versions.

Also note the missing `__locale_t` is mentioned in several places, e.g. [this bugreport](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10456). I could just add `#include <xlocale.h>` in some files, but it seems the proper solution would be to get `__USE_XOPEN2K8` to be set.

---

Edit: I've found [this thread](http://readlist.com/lists/gcc.gnu.org/gcc-help/4/21431.html) describing the problem. Apparently, headers of the host system get "fixincluded" into the headers of the new compiler. The linked post suggests to edit features.h. Does anyone know if I have to recompile gcc / glibc afterwards (and how to get it to pick up the new features.h, rather than overwriting it)?

Comment: Per the link that you included, the problem is that, when you built gcc, it created copies of the system C library header files instead of the headers from your custom glibc.  The key is going to be to point the gcc build at your glibc build.  Sadly, I'm not completely sure how to do that, or I'd post an answer.  Looking at the options to gcc's configure, `--oldincludedir` or `--with-build-sysroot` *might* be in the right direction, but I'm mostly guessing.

Comment: @rra - I still compile latest GCC on RHEL5 and run it on later OSes. This requires manually removing several of the headers in include-fixed; namely `features.h`, `pthread.h`, `wchar.h`, `sys/stat.h`, and `bits/string2.h`. As near as I can tell, "fixincludes" has actually been "breakincludes" for at least a decade now.

Answer (score 6):

When `__USE_GNU` is defined, `__USE_XOPEN2K8` is always defined as well, unless you
are explicitly defining or undefining these macros, which you must not do.
Use `_GNU_SOURCE`, `_XOPEN_SOURCE {500,600,700,...}` etc. macros before including
the first header instead. This is the recommended way to select the GNU feature set in glibc headers, together with defining it on the command line (`-D_GNU_SOURCE`).

Alternatively, you can try specifying GNU extension usage to gcc through the `-std` command line switch (`gnu89`, `gnu99`, and so forth).

Answer (score 3):

On CentOS7 with gcc 4.6 we had to use -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700 -D__USE_XOPEN2K8

Answer (score 3):

The glibc `__USE_`* macros are internal macros used to implement feature selection.  The supported way to set them is to define feature test macros such as `-D_GNU_SOURCE`:

- [Feature Test Macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html)

These macros are needed because glibc supports many standards and GNU extensions, and these features are in conflict with each other, mostly due to the lack of namespaces in C.  For example, C and POSIX allow you to define a global variable called `secure_getenv` (because the identifier is not reserved or otherwise used by those standards), but such a program will not work if you compile with `_GNUS_SOURCE` and include `<stdlib.h>` because glibc provides a function called `secure_getenv`.

`<xlocale.h>` is an internal glibc header (a comment within the header file says so) and will no longer be available in glibc 2.26.

Answer (score 0):

As I know when we use the complier, it's behavior depends on some ENV macros, which saved in `feature.h`. So you can configure your complier by modifyinfg it.
Fisrt,you need use `g++ -E youfile > log`, to see which `feature.h` file your complier use, and then use `g++ -E -dM /path/to/feature.h>log`, to find the `__USE_XOPEN2K8`, if you can't find it. Add `#define __USE_XOPEN2K8 1` at the end of the file.You know may be you have do some configure wrong when you install you complier.