# error: '__getdelim' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, gcc, libc

I am trying to build the same code on 2 machines with the following config:

1. `RHEL 5.8`, `gcc 4.3.2`, `libc  2.5`
2. `RHEL 6.4` , `gcc 4.3.2`, `libc 2.12`

In the second machine(which has newer config) on a simple line like:

```
#include <string>
```

running the following command:

```
 /opt/.../bin/c++  -Dmy_packet_EXPORTS -fPIC -Wall \
-Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align \
-mtune=generic -fstrict-aliasing -g -O1 -I/dev2/build/my_packet/include \
-I/dev2/source/my_packet/include  -I/dev2/source/my_packet/src   \
-o CMakeFiles/my_packet.dir/version.cpp.o \
-c  /dev2/source/my_packet/src/my_packet/version.cpp
```

I am getting build error:

```
/usr/include/bits/stdio.h: In function '__ssize_t getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*)':
/usr/include/bits/stdio.h:118: error: '__getdelim' was not declared in this scope
```

Anybody has a clue what the error is and how to solve it please? 
thanks

Comment: yep, nothing that I could understand. Some people speak about __USE_GNU macro but I need more specific information, if any.

Comment: Have you tried to install a different version of gcc on any of the machines? If so, how did you do that?

Comment: Here,there are 10s of build machines, each having many versions that I (might)can use. the problem is I dont know where it stems from. I just supplied the config versions to mark the difference but I am still not what to setup/modify/config?? and which element of the chain??

Comment: For the sake of test, based on some random recommendations in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879302/purpose-of-use-xopen2k8-and-how-to-set-it?s=1|1.4518 ,  I added `-D__USE_XOPEN2K8` and build error was gone. Still, this blind try/error is not the what I have in mind. Perhaps it can give you a clue to help me out understand the concept.

Comment: Sorry I think I misunderstood your question. It was my impression that you are just compiling a file that contains this single line, and getting an error.