# How to use langinfo.h features in glibc without breaking compilation in FreeBSD based system?

Tags: gcc, posix, freebsd, glibc

I am trying to make the following code work on both Linux and FreeBSD based system, Is it a valid usage of macros `__GLIBC__` and `__USE_XOPEN2K8`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <langinfo.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <xlocale.h>

int main(void) {
//#if defined(__GLIBC__) && defined (__USE_XOPEN2K8)
    locale_t    loc;
    char *locale_messages = "en-US.utf-8";
    loc = newlocale(LC_ALL_MASK, locale_messages, (locale_t)0);
    if (loc != NULL)
    {
        char    result[256]; 

        sprintf(result, "%s_%s.%s",
            nl_langinfo_l(_NL_IDENTIFICATION_LANGUAGE, loc),
            nl_langinfo_l(_NL_IDENTIFICATION_TERRITORY, loc),
            nl_langinfo_l(CODESET, loc));
    }
//#endif 
}
```

If I don't use those directives, I get the following error on mac OS. I want to disable that code to avoid the following errors.

```
 error: use of undeclared identifier '_NL_IDENTIFICATION_LANGUAGE'
            nl_langinfo_l(_NL_IDENTIFICATION_LANGUAGE, loc),
                          ^
 error: use of undeclared identifier '_NL_IDENTIFICATION_TERRITORY'
            nl_langinfo_l(_NL_IDENTIFICATION_TERRITORY, loc),
```

I have found one [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879302/purpose-of-use-xopen2k8-and-how-to-set-it/18985859#18985859) recommending use _GNU_SOURCE and _XOPEN_SOURCE, but as result above code is disabled on my linux system too. It seems I need to define _GNU_SOURCE before using it, but before proceding with this idea, can we work  with `__GLIBC__` and `__USE_XOPEN2K8`.

Comment: The code is for user-space program. Why do you use "linux-kernel" tag which is for Linux kernel code?

Comment: My appologies, That was by mistake, I have modified the tag.

Comment: `I get the following error on mac OS` So disable them on mac. `#if !THIS_IS_MAC` `result above code is disabled on my linux system too` Please create a full compilable [MCVE]? What compiler and compiler options and compiler versions are you using? Did you add `_XOPEN_SOURCE` and `_GNU_SOURCE` __on top__ of your file? If you did not, please read `man 7 feature_test_macros`.

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm compiling it as follows '$ cc test.c -o test', I am not giving any compiling option.
$ cc --version
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

Comment: I don't know if it applies to this problem but, while large portions of macOS come from FreeBSD, macOS itself is not FreeBSD.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
#indef __FreeBSD__
#endif
```

preprocessor directives to ignore the code that shouldn't be built on FreeBSD. However `man nl_langinfo_l` on FreeBSD says that this function is present on FreeBSD, so you shouldn't have any problems with it.

Comment: Thanks, @arrowd, this is one option, but it will be better if we can have something specific to GNU lib because the same code needs to be portable on other systems as well.

Answer (score 0):

The *best* way is to use a build system to detect if that option is available and then conditionally enable that part of code depending of the detection result. This is how `autotools` project came to be - to detect differences between operating systems.

In cmake you could:

```
include(CheckCSourceCompiles)
check_c_source_compiles("
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define _SOMETHING_READ_FEATURE_TEST_MACROS
#include <something something that is needed.h>
int main() { return _NL_IDENTIFICATION_TERRITORY; }
" WE_HAVE_NL_IDENTIFICATION_TERRITORY)
if(WE_HAVE_NL_IDENTIFICATION_TERRITORY)
     target_add_definitions(your_target PUBLIC LIB_HAS_NL_IDENTIFICATION_TERRITORY)
endif()
```

and then use your own `LIB_HAS_NL_IDENTIFICATION_TERRITORY` macro that detect if that option is available or not. Such solution is stable, easy to port and dynamically reacts to environment changes.